# Error mounting filesystem when mounting external hdd

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, udisks

---

I'm sure this has been asked lots of times, but I have checked many threads and couldn't find the fix to my specific problem.

So I have been using an external hard disk (Toshiba external usb 3.0 1TB) for well over ten years. This one has all my important files and memories, and one day (two days ago) it just stopped working on my Windows 10 PC and my Windows 7 PC. I have tried everything but the PC jut freezes and becomes unresponsive unless I unplug the hard drive. I tried it on my LED TV and it works fine.

So I downloaded ubuntu to try to see if Ubuntu could view the files, at least it knows the label of the hdd, size, and free space, but can't mount it. When I try to mount it I get this error

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at media/*user*/*HDDLABEL*:Unknow error when mountimg /dev/sdb1 (udisks-error-quark-0)

Any help? Please I'm really desperate.

Answer (score 2):

Hard drives can fail. That is why you have copies of important files and memories on at least two drives, but preferably more. Then, when a drive fails, you do not loose your data.

You used the drive for 10 years. That is a long time for a hard drive to remain operational. Windows 10 does not anymore recognize it. That, now, also Ubuntu does not recognize it confirms you might be dealing with a drive that is end of life. You already tried different computers and now a different operating system. Make sure you also try a different connection cables - it still could be just that.

If all fails, and you do not have any backup of that data, then date recovery will be your only option to try to recover at least something. Using professional services will likely be most successful, but that tends to be very expensive.

Comment: I used to use it on my Windows 7 PC, worked fine until I changed to Windows 10. It worked alright for a few months. However, the hard drive is still operational as my TV recognizes it and the videos and images are intact. If I wanted to seek out  professional services, what would be the price range for it? And which service would be best? I don't want to deal with scammers.

Comment: Unusual that it works on a TV, but not on any computer. Then, there is still hope. Not sure which professional services are out there in your area.

Comment: Well I might better try to look up data recovery services nearby so that this won't happen again. Thanks anyway mate!